# zfs replication temporary file

Tags: solaris, zfs, replication, nexenta

I'm running a zfs replication task, of a snapshot size ~2.5GB. 
I see that there is traffic going between the master and the slave, by using snoop, but I want to monitor the transmission. Is there a temporary file that I can see being created?

It's Nexenta OS on both master and slave.

Comment: I add a similar situation recently, but you can't see anything besides the destination increasing. In my case was send and receive . But even using -v option, only at the end of the operation it tells you how long it took and the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by seeing the destination increasing? How did you see it? some zfs command?
and if you can see the destination snapshot size growing, you can monitor by percentage of the total snapshot, don't you?

Comment: that's manual work, but on the destination you can do zfs list -t snapshot and check how much space is use.

Comment: oh, well i already use zfs list -t snapshot, but i don't see the snapshot that is being transmitted...
that's why i asked if there is a temporary file created somewhere :) should i see it being created in by zfs list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to watch it, directly via ZFS send or receive.  Solaris 11.2 does have some verbosity available in zfs send that would allow you to gauge process.

If you have access to the script, you could pipe the zfs send through 'pv' to watch progress, if that would be helpful enough.